# for loop, for radio buttons on a table

Tags: c#, asp.net

hey guys i have these code in my web:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"><table>
      <tr>
           <td>
              <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbParametroExterno" Text="[P] Parametro Externo" runat="server"
                                                    Enabled="False" /><br />
              <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbDatoGeneral" Text="[G] Dato General" runat="server" Enabled="False" /><br />
              <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbFormula" Text="[F] Formula" runat="server" Enabled="False" /><br />
              <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbFormulaAcumulable" Text="[A] Formula Acumulable" runat="server"
                                       Enabled="False" /><br />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbDatoFijo" Text="[D] Dato Fijo" runat="server" Enabled="False" /><br />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbDatoVariable" Text="[V] Dato Variable" runat="server" Enabled="False" /><br />
              <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbFuncionInterna" Text="[I] Funcion Interna" runat="server"
                                                    Enabled="False" /><br />
              <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbTablaSistema" Text="[T] Tabla del Sistema" runat="server"
                                                    Enabled="False" /><br />
           </td>
       </tr>
</table></Panel>
```

i need to loop through all of them, so i can enable them to true when i click a button, i was trying with a foreach, but it doesnt seem to work, if you could help me that'd be cool, thank you!

```
protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{    
foreach (Control c in Panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (c is RadioButton)
        {

            if (((RadioButton)c).Enabled == false)
            {
                ((RadioButton)c).Enabled = true;
            }
        }

    }
 }
```

i'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  What does `Panel1.Controls` contain at runtime?  Does it enter the `foreach` loop?

Comment: Please elaborate on "it doesn't seem to work". Are you getting an error? Does nothing happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your storing all the radio buttons and button inside a form, which is also inside the Panel. Unfortunately there are more sub controls inside the panel than just the radio buttons. Try something like this:

ASP.NET

```
    protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        EnableAllRadioSubControls(Panel1);
    }

    protected void EnableAllRadioSubControls(Control ccontrol)
    {
        foreach (Control c in ccontrol.Controls)
        {
            if(c.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                EnableAllRadioSubControls(c);
            }else{
                if (c is RadioButton)
                {

                    if (((RadioButton)c).Enabled == false)
                    {
                        ((RadioButton)c).Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

C#

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<table>
      <tr>
           <td>
              <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbParametroExterno" Text="[P] Parametro Externo" runat="server"
                                                    Enabled="False" /><br />
              <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbDatoGeneral" Text="[G] Dato General" runat="server" Enabled="False" /><br />
              <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbFormula" Text="[F] Formula" runat="server" Enabled="False" /><br />
              <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbFormulaAcumulable" Text="[A] Formula Acumulable" runat="server"
                                       Enabled="False" /><br />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbDatoFijo" Text="[D] Dato Fijo" runat="server" Enabled="False" /><br />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbDatoVariable" Text="[V] Dato Variable" runat="server" Enabled="False" /><br />
              <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbFuncionInterna" Text="[I] Funcion Interna" runat="server"
                                                    Enabled="False" /><br />
              <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbTablaSistema" Text="[T] Tabla del Sistema" runat="server"
                                                    Enabled="False" /><br />
           </td>
       </tr>
</table>

<asp:Button ID="btnNew" Text="Clickme" runat="server" onclick="btnNew_Click" />
</form>
</asp:Panel>
```

This will iterate through all the controls until it finds the radio button sub controls and enables them. :)